# EditText onclick action only executed when refocussing the EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, imeoptions

I am trying to create a simple editText for which I defined a simple onclick action that outputs the name to the window again. 
My problem is, that it seems like this action is only called when I refocus the editText again. 
So I focus the editText, type in my name and hit enter. Now the window closes but the name is not put to the window. When I focus the editText again, then the name is put to the window.

When I do exactly the same without having the android:imeOptions="actionDone" set in the XML, everything works fine (except of the keyboard does not close, which does not close of course)

My editText from the XML:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/name_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:onClick="readName" />
```

My readName() method:

```
public void readName(View view) {
        EditText nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_edit_text);
        String nameWorking = nameEditText.getText().toString();
        name = nameWorking;
        displayOrderSummary();
    }
```

Comment: can you show the code of your activity and siplayOrderSummary() as well?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what your entire activity looks like, but I believe that if you remove the binding outside of your `readName()` method, it should work fine.

Place the code below into your `onCreate()`.

`EditText nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_edit_text);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `android:onClick` you may put the following inside the `onCreate()` method:

```java
EditText nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_edit_text);
nameEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        readName(v)
    }
}
```

Comment: This leads to exactly the same behavior. It works fine without android:imeOptions="actionDone", but when having this set, the name is only changed when reopening the EditText. 

Can it be, that the method onClick is only called when tapping the EditText? This would explain my problem: The listener fires, when I tap the EditText. The first time, no name is in the box so name is left blank. When I close, the listener doesn't care so it doesn't change anything. When I reopen it fires again and changes name.

But what I would need is a listener that fires when closing/unfocusing the EditText